# How to update attachment in ActiveStorage (Rails 5.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I recently upgraded my project to the latest Rails version (5.2) to get `ActiveStorage` - a library that handles attachment uploads to cloud services like AWS S3, Google Cloud etc..

Almost everything works fine. I can upload and attach images with

```
user.avatar.attach(params[:file])
```

and receive it with

```
user.avatar.service_url
```

But now I want to replace/update an user's avatar. I thought I can run

```
user.avatar.attach(params[:file])
```

again. But this throws an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to remove the existing associated avatar_attachment. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil.
```

What is that suppoed to mean? How can I change an users avatar?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## The cause of the error

This error is being raised by the `has_one` association between your model and the attachment record. It occurs because trying to replace the original attachment with a new one will orphan the original and cause it to fail the foreign key constraint for `belongs_to` associations. This is the behavior for all ActiveRecord `has_one` relationships (i.e. it’s not specific to ActiveStorage).

## An analogous example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile
end
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

# create a new user record
user = User.create!

# create a new associated profile record (has_one)
original_profile = user.create_profile!

# attempt to replace the original profile with a new one
user.create_profile! 
 => ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to remove the existing associated profile. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil.
```

In attempting to create a new profile, ActiveRecord tries to set the `user_id` of the original profile to `nil`, which fails the foreign key constraint for `belongs_to` records. I believe this is essentially what is happening when you try and attach a new file to your model using ActiveStorage... doing so tries to nullify the foreign key of the original attachment record, which will fail.

## The solution

The solution for `has_one` relationships is to destroy the associated record before trying to create a new one (i.e. purging the attachment before trying to attach another one).

```
user.avatar.purge # or user.avatar.purge_later
user.avatar.attach(params[:file])
```

## Is this desired behavior?

Whether or not ActiveStorage should automatically purge the original record when trying to attach a new one for has_one relationships is a different question best posed to the core team...

IMO having it work consistently with all other has_one relationships makes sense, and it may be preferable to leave it up to the developer to be explicit about purging an original record before attaching a new one rather than doing it automatically (which may be a bit presumptuous).

**Resources:**

- [Source code for `has_one` error raising behavior](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_one_association.rb#L92)
- [Test case for `has_one` error raising behavior](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/associations/has_one_associations_test.rb#L479)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: This commit from the same day of this answer fixes this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/656ee8b2dd1b06541f03ea19302d3529085f5139#diff-220c5602a1721b74f7ee61a8e09699da

Comment: Carlos, I'm getting the same error I have a User that has a profile and the profile has_one_attach `:avatar` However, I get the same error. I'm doing the create method this way? `def create
    @profile = current_user.create_profile(profile_params)
  end`

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469191/activemodelunknownattributeerror-unknown-attribute-avatar-activestorage`

Comment: Beautifully explained sir. ty

Answer (score 8):

You can call `purge_later` before `attach` when using `has_one_attached`:

```rb
user.avatar.purge_later
user.avatar.attach(params[:file])
```

**Update**

[Rails now purges previous attachment automatically (since Aug 29th)](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/656ee8b2dd1b06541f03ea19302d3529085f5139#diff-220c5602a1721b74f7ee61a8e09699da).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem the with image saving. I hope this will help

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

let look at the form and controller

```
= simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :email
    = f.input :avatar, as: :file

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
def create
    @user = User.new(post_params)
    @user.avatar.attach(params[:post][:avatar])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: but what if I'm trying to do it this way ```def create
    @profile = current_user.create_profile(profile_params)
  end```

Comment: So I assume you have a method in `user.rb` model called `create_profile` and you already paste the params, in the method you do for example: `self.profile.attach(params[:post][:profile])`. And look at the `current_user` if it is the helper method of the `devise` gem or the actual `user` object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469191/activemodelunknownattributeerror-unknown-attribute-avatar-activestorage  Here is the post for the issue I'm having. Which I belive is because of the way I'm passing the attached file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nested attributes and no other attribute has changed in child model, Rails won't automatically detect changes to your attachment. To do so, you must override the `changed_for_autosave?` method :

```
def Child
  belongs_to :parent
  has_one_attached :attachment

  # Magic happens here
  def changed_for_autosave?
    super || attachment.changed_for_autosave?
  end
end

def Parent
  has_many :children

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end
```

This also triggers the child models callbacks (`before_save`, ...) on parent save.
I don't know if this approach works without nested attributes, but I suppose it does.
In general, this kind of logic shouldn't be handled inside controllers as many suggested (in my opinion).

It took me a while to figure, I hope this helps. Cheers !

Comment: no need to add `changed_for_autosave?` for rails >= 6.0.3 [Fix #37701 Autosave association bug with ActiveStorage::Attachments #37786](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37786)