# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError unknown attribute 'avatar' - ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

Currently I'm trying to attach an `:avatar` field on a Profile. I get the following error:
[image]

However, following the docs I added the relationshipt of `:avatar` to Profile.

```
models/profile.rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

I also add `:avatar` in the strong params. In the Profile controllers.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @profile = current_user.create_profile(profile_params)
  end
  ##
  private

  def profile_params
     params.require(:profile).permit(:full_name, :city, :bio, :avatar)
  end
end
```

I wonder if the issue is because of the association between User and Profile. A user has one profile and profile belongs to user.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :photos
  has_one :profile
end
```

I request in the `profiles/new.html.erb` as a file attachement:

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :avatar %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar, as: :file, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

I see that in the params that the file is in avatar which is why I find so confusing that it doesn't recognize `:avatar` as an attribute.

```
Started POST "/profiles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-22 17:55:26 -0400
Processing by ProfilesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==", "profile"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff62db322b8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/86/g7_xcx392qn815kmkcm55ydc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20180922-10194-awlxd1.png>, @original_filename="profile.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile[avatar]\"; filename=\"profile.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">
```

I was able to upload attachement for another model so it's not something with the installation. Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I would make sure that you've killed your server, and if you're using Spring, try restarting that. I've had plenty of weird issues with Rails 5 because code reloading didn't work correctly.

Comment: @Nate does restaring `rails server` restarts Spring? or how can I restart Spring? Yes, I reload the server

Comment: The spring process starts when you first boot up the rails app, and just keeps running in the background, making subsequent `rails server` loads faster. Try running `spring stop` from the root of your app (same folder that you'd run `rails server` from), and then run `rails server` again and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @nate that wasn't it

Comment: Bummer. Sorry, not sure then. I've never used Active Storage.

Comment: Are you still having this problem.

Comment: Are you using rails 6.0.0.rc1 and ActiveStorage::Downloading?