# Retain previous attachment (rather than purging) when adding a new has_one_attached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45870021/5783745) superb question and [even better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45941253/5783745) demonstrate that (after this [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870021/how-to-update-attachment-in-activestorage-rails-5-2#comment79398904_45941253)) rails automatically purges an old attachment when a new one is uploaded to a has_one_attached.

But suppose, for record keeping purposes, you need to keep old attachments, rather than purge them.

Is there a conventional or 'out of the box' Active Storage way to do this?

#### Specific example

Say a user uploads an attachment. Then uploads a second attachment, then a third.

Desired behaviour is that user.image should return the third image (as expected), but somehow, the first two images should be retained.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default the record will be purged. However, you can overwrite this behaviour by setting the `:dependent` option to `:purge_later`